# fitsSystemWindows effect gone for either one of two fragments with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android-fragments, statusbar, transparent, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an activity (contains 4 fragments) with transparent status bar. Two of the four fragments have AppBarLayout to collapse the toolbar. In order to avoid the AppBarLayout was draw behind the transparent status bar, I have:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/first_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:statusBarBackground="@color/blue"
    >
```

and

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/second_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:statusBarBackground="@color/yellow"
    >
```

in the these two fragments. I added android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for both of the fragment.

However, only one of the two fragments work properly. One is draw BELOW the status bar while the other one is still draw BEHIND the status bar. Do you guys have any idea why only one works?

Thanks!